# hyperlinks in an array, android

Tags: java, arrays, hyperlink, textview

So I have an array that's displaying results in a textview in my android application. It's working fine, but I would like the result to work like a standard hyperlink, so you click the text and you get redirected to an external page in your phones browser.

```
public void init()
{
    paintnamewords = new String[] {"102,255,102","No","Jupiter","Saturn","Gravity","Venus"};
    answers = new String[] {"Mercury","No","Jupiter","Saturn","Gravity","Venus"};
    colourbbox2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.colortext2);
    paintname111 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.paintname);
    savebtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.savebtn);
    savebtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            checkcolour();
        }
    });
}
```

So for example the word mercury would be displayed , you touch it and you get redirected, any help would be wonderful !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@leo666, this will work for your idea.

```
TextView myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textName);
myTextView.setText("Here is google : www.google.com");
Linkify.addLinks(myTextView, Linkify.WEB_URLS);
```

Also make your Textview to have this property in xml

```
android:autoLink="web"
```